# signIn with Devise from an API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise

I have a problem with the user authentication.  I exposed a user API and the json output is like this:

```
[
    {
         id: 1,
         email: "khelif.ghassen@gmail.com",
         nom: "Ghassen",
         prenom: "Khelif",
         created_at: "2017-11-05T03:18:19.640Z",
         updated_at: "2017-11-05T03:18:19.644Z"
    }
]
```

I can't see the crypted password

Comment: Please add the controller code that is returning the JSON shown above.  Add that code to your question please.

Comment: @Ghassen Khelif Share your respected json.jbuilder code from the view

Comment: here is my code that returns the JSON

Answer (score 0):

for this moment I'm just showing up all users (I have just on user for this moment) and this is my class to return this JSON

`

```
module TESTAPP
  module V1
    class Users < Grape::API
      version 'v1', using: :path
      format :json
      prefix :api
      resource :users do
        desc "Return list of users"
  get do
    User.all
  end

  desc "Return an objet"
  params do
    requires :id, type: Integer, desc: "User id"
  end
  route_param :id do
    get do
      User.find(params[:id])
    end
  end
end

end
end
end
```